# Yii array with values in dropdown list

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller, yii, model

I have a dropdown list that gets data from a function, the function pulls a list of all files in a certain folder. However, i need to capture the value of the file name, so i need to output the array with both value and name. Here's my code;

function in model;

```
public static function getEmailNewUserView() {
        $files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.mail'), array('absolutePaths'=>false));
        return $files;
    }
```

HTML element in _form

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
        $model,
        'email_newuser_view',
        array(
            'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'col-md-6',
            ),
            'widgetOptions' => array(
                'data' => Options::model()->getEmailNewUserView(),
            )
        )
    ); ?>
```

This outputs;

```
<option value="0">item</option>
```

I need it it output

```
<option value="item">item</option>
```

Anyone know how to do this in Yii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/array-combine)

```
public static function getEmailNewUserView() {
    $files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.mail'), array('absolutePaths'=>false));
    return array_combine($files, $files);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edofre, exactly what i was looking for